# Does Wordpress run a post query when a page is invoked?

Tags: query-posts

Let's say I create a what in the Wordpress backend is called a page (pages - new page). I put some arbitrary page elements on it (e.g. title, text, some images, a widget or two displaying posts from various categories). I don't assign a particular template to it, so the (whatever) theme's default template is used. I publish that page, and now somebody clicks on it.

What is the data and control flow of Wordpress now?

Does it execute a post query before/when loading the page, eventually using some filters (which)?

Comment: Pages are posts of type `page`, they're stored and handled internally the same way, with the same APIs, there is no difference

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. Pages are just a type of post.

If you visit, say, `https://test.test/sample-page/`, then this happens:

1. WordPress checks the URL against its stored rewrite rules.
2. On a normal site, `https://test.test/sample-page/` will match `(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$`, which the rule maps to `index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]`.
3. WordPress performs a query using `WP_Query`, with the `pagename` argument set to `pagename`. Our URL doesn't include a page number, so it will be whatever the default is.
4. WordPress recognises this as a query for a single Page, and sets the appropriate values for the `is_page`, `is_singular` etc. properties of the query. `is_main_query` will also be true for the query based on the URL parameters.
5. Recognising that this is a query for a page, WordPress loads the appropriate template from the theme using the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

There's a lot more that goes on, but this is the basic overview. A huge number of action and filter hooks are fired during this process, so I can't list them all here, but `WP_Query` related hooks like `pre_get_posts` *do* run when viewing pages.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you are telling me. Actually I was trying to figure what a post loop contained in a page template does. Does this mean that any post loop in the template loaded will be fully executed, iterating through all posts in my database? Will that post loop return each post in the database, regardless whether it's a page, or a "post" post, or a "blog entry" post?

Comment: A post loop in a page template is no different to a post loop anywhere else. Page templates are not special, the only special part is that WP sees an option telling it to load that template instead of the one it originally planned for

Comment: Note that this answer is basically the long answer I wrote for your other question but with less detail

Comment: @karx11erx In a page template the `have_posts()` loop contains the results of step 3, which should just contain one page. Honestly, you're asking such abstract questions that at this point I have no idea what you're even trying to do. I don't understand what "any post loop in the template loaded will be fully executed, iterating through all posts in my database" is supposed to mean. What do you mean by "any post loop" and "fully executed"?

Comment: @Jacob: Thank you, that answer helped me.

Comment: @Tom: Your answer was hard to understand, so I am now trying to get the details. What I have now understood is that when invoking a WP page using the permalink, in the end WP knows which page template to load and which (user made) page(s) to load. When the page template's post loop is executed, a the_page() call inside that loop would load these (user made) page(e). Any php code inside that page needs to create its individual post loop if it would e.g. want to display blog posts. Correct?

Comment: no, before the template is loaded WordPress already has a query, and has already fetched the posts. How else would it know which template to load or if it's a 404? The post loop is just a really fancy way to do a `foreach`, and `the_post` just sets up some global variables. No _"loading"_ occurs because it has already happened. I strongly recommend you read about the `WP_Query` object and its use, it will make things much clearer and save a lot of time

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. How I understand it, WP does a query filtering the required posts (pages) and loads the query result (i.e. post(s)) into memory. The template's post loop will basically loop through these posts (one of which or the only one being my page). Now how does my individual page content interact with the template and its post loop? I technically understand the post loop. But what sense does the post loop make when it has nothing to do with what I put in my page? You're saying the_post() only sets up a few variables, so when will e.g. php code in my page be executed?

Comment: I need to be frank: Your follow up questions demonstrate you have not really understood. You're asking for certain details on how things work, but seem to lack the knowledge needed for that information to be useful. If you want to get started developing for WordPress, these questions are _not_ the right place to start. There are many resources available for learning WordPress development you'd be much better off consulting first. You might even understand things better if you just view the source of the functions that you're using, so that you can see where things are coming from.